# Add line spacing to textView not working

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add line spacing to textView. With the following code I get an error "textView has no member attributedText".
How can I solve this problem?

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol TextViewCellProtocol:NSObjectProtocol {
    func textViewCellDidTouchedButton(_ cell:TextViewCell)
}

class TextViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     @IBOutlet var textView:FuriganaTextView!

     let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
     style.lineSpacing = 40
     let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
     textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: textView.text,
                                                             attributes: attributes)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting the error because the textView class that you are using (`FuriganaTextView`) doesn't have a member `attributedText`. After checking their [gitHub documentation](https://github.com/lingochamp/FuriganaTextView). I guess you could add attributed text to `FuriganaTextView` by specifying the attributed string to the `contents` property of `FuriganaTextView` like

```
textView.contents = NSAttributedString(string: textView.text,
                                                         attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: Hello It seems to be a right track, but i am getting another error. "value of type "FuriganatextView" has no member "text". "

Comment: Thank you a lot:)

Comment: @risa8 
 
Try using textView.contentView?.text

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks for your kind help:)

Answer (score 0):

`FuriganaTextView` is build over TextKit not a subclass of UITextView. YOu can set attributeed string by using `furiganaTextView.contents` property. Here is [usage example](https://github.com/lingochamp/FuriganaTextView#usage).

```
// Prepare furigana contents
// Note: The order of the furiganas provided to the FuriganaTextView is important.
// It must be ascending in manner of the location of the range,
// otherwise the furiganas may not be rendered at the correct position.
let furiganas = [
  Furigana(text: "た", original: "田", range: NSMakeRange(0, 1)),
  Furigana(text: "なか", original: "中", range: NSMakeRange(1, 1)),
]
let contents = NSAttributedString(string: "田中さん、中華料理を食べたことありますか。")

// Tell FuriganaTextView about 
// the furiganas (which is an array of the Furigana struct) 
// and the contents to display (a NSAttributedString)
furiganaTextView.furiganas = furiganas
furiganaTextView.contents = contents

// To customize the text view, use the contentView
// contentView will return a valid UITextView after
// the contents has been set
furiganaTextView.contentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
```